# typescript import { SomeType } from './types' throw error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack

Our company has a project that using webpack 4 + babel 7.x + typescript 3.8, As the project get bigger, I need to improve the build speed, I am trying to replace babel with ts-loader or swc-loader, which then results in the error:

```
import React, { FC, useState, useEffect } from 'react'
throw error ↓ //  All of syntax `import { SomeType } from 'FILE|MODULE'` throw error

ERROR in ./src/pages/merchandise/manage/merchandise_list/create/type.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-hot-loader/node_modules/@types/react' in '/Users/jawei/Desktop/gm_projects/erp/src/pages/merchandise/manage/merchandise_list/create'
@ ./src/pages/merchandise/manage/merchandise_list/create/type.ts 7:0-53
@ ./src/pages/merchandise/manage/components/upload_images/index.tsx
@ ./src/pages/system/shop_decoration/student_meal/shop_background/index.tsx
@ ./src/pages/system/shop_decoration/student_meal/index.page.tsx
@ ./src/pages lazy index\.page\.
@ ./src/frame/index.tsx
@ ./src/index.tsx
@ multi react-hot-loader/patch ./src/index
```

If change the import syntax to :

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import type { FC } from 'react'
```

It will work normally，but there are too many codes like this, I don't want change every file, is there a way to make ts-loader compatible with this syntax?